# What other wallets can import Qt's backup .dat file?

Tags: bitcoin-core, backup, wallet-import

I've been using Bitcoin Qt on my work computer (my only working computer at the moment) but last week Windows 7 decided that the program's bypassing the firewall to download the blockchain was a security risk and blocked it from doing so. I'm not the network administrator and fiddling with the firewall settings I *can* access hasn't done anything. While it is absolutely possible that I am missing some obvious solution, I've given up on fixing this. what I'd like to do now is download another offline wallet - one that does not need the entire blockchain - and import my Qt backup. I've tried MultiBit & Electrum, neither of which seem to work (although, again, it is possible that I'm missing something). Is there another program I can use? Should I wait until my laptop is fixed and just re-install BTC Qt on that? Am I out of luck?

Comment: fyi: Using the default (or semi-default) settings, when Windows 7 blocks Bitcoin-qt it will still be able to download the blockchain.

Comment: @Tom van der Woerdt: But it won't sync. It says “0 active connections to bitcoin network.”

Comment: see http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2300/copy-wallet-to-electrum-or-multibit. - based on the info given by Gary Rowe, Multibit should support wallet.dat imports, although I couldn't find any evidence of this on their site.  When I switched to Electrum, I dumped my old wallet using pywallet and then copied the relevant private keys over(only like 5 of them had any balance, and they were all labelled which made them easier to locate).    If you choose an online wallet, I believe most of them can import using the pasted output of `pywallet.py -dumpwallet`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PyWallet](https://github.com/joric/pywallet), a simple tool for exporting `wallet.dat` files, to retrieve the [private keys](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Private_key) for your wallet addresses.

[Most wallets](http://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet) nowadays can import private keys, which give direct access to all the funds in your backed up wallet.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use PyWallet, but it looks like the perfect solution. I'll try it and see.

Answer (score 1):

Any PC that can run any software that would be able to import `wallet.dat` can surely also run **bitcoind**.  You do not need to download the blockchain, not even to have a network connection.

1) Put `wallet.dat` in a proper folder and run bitcoind.

2) Then use another console to do:

> bitcoind walletpassphrase *password* 3600

3) and then you can just export any of the keys you need, using:

> bitcoind dumpprivkey *publicaddr*

If you don't have any password over your wallet, just skip point 2.

Comment: What does the 36000 do? (yes I'm too lazy to look it up :P. Didn't think importing wallet.dat would take more than 5 min. Turns out I was very, very wrong!)