# Bitcoin-Qt wallet is taking forever to synchronise. Can I just use the same address elsewhere to collect coins?

Tags: blockchain, wallet, bitcoin-core, synchronization

It will take several days before the wallet is in sync. I already purchased a bitcoin and am waiting for it to transfer into my account using the address that was generated by Bitcoin-Qt. Can I just re-divert the Bitcoin to a cloud-based wallet that doesn't need to synchronize?

Comment: [If you want to speed up the blockchain sync use bootstrap.dat](https://github.com/conformal/btcd/wiki/Using-bootstrap.dat#wiki-Obtaining)

Comment: closely related to [Cannot access my bitcoins because my wallet is still synchronising. What can I do to retrieve them?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/6056/5406)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the syncing is not advancing? If you hover the icon in the lower right corner, you should see the block count. Can you see it increase?

You can export your client's [`wallet.dat`](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Data_directory) file and import it into [a new Bitcoin-Qt wallet](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10974/import-wallet-dat-into-a-new-bitcoin-qt-client) or into [another Bitcoin wallet](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10095/what-other-wallets-can-import-qts-backup-dat-file), either using the `wallet.dat` file directly or by extracting the private keys from it.

Comment: It says "Catching up" 14900 out of 242000 or something like that... I would really just rather not have to go through that! so if I export that file wallet.dat, the transaction will show up in my new wallet?

Comment: What you also can do is just delete all files in your data folder **only keeping the wallet.dat file**. That's the only one you need to access your coins, if you delete the others, the syncing will restart.
Make sure you have enough space in the data folder btw, this data can take up to 10 GB of space.

Comment: I cannot locate the folder under Library/Application Support!

Comment: You need to go to your Home folder first. I don't know exactly how you do it in Mac (I use Mac as well and got frustrated many time about how hard it is), but you need to get Finder to show hidden folders. The Library folder in your Home folder is hidden. In there, there should be a Application Support/Bitcoin folder with the data.

Answer (score 1):

Open Bitcoin-qt.

Go Help > Debug window. Then click "console" tab.

Type

> dumpprivkey [the address you sent it too]

Go to https://blockchain.info/wallet/

Click "Create my free wallet", and do so.

Log in. Go to "Import / export".

Under "Import Private Key" enter what the terminal returned.

Comment: Unless you really understand how wallets work, this is likely shooting yourself in the foot. The wallet uses a new change address for every transaction, so unless you're very careful to include those (they are usually hidden), you'll miss things.

Comment: [If you want to speed up the blockchain sync use bootstrap.dat](https://github.com/conformal/btcd/wiki/Using-bootstrap.dat#wiki-Obtaining)

Answer (score -1):

It's important to first set:

```
type: walletpassphrase “your walletpassphrase” 600

type: dumpprivkey [your wallet string]
```

Comment: A brief explanation of what this does and why it is important would improve your answer. People may be reluctant to follow instructions without a reason.

Comment: Could you expand on this answer?