# Can I import my wallet from my bitcoin core for electrum?

Tags: bitcoind, electrum, wallet-import

Bitcoin-qt, now bitcoin core is insane. It consumes 40GB hard disk space. It hogs network. I am thinking of using Electrum or something like that.

I want to use another bitcoin client.

Electrum is one of them. However, I got asicminer stocks that send me dividend. I want to import my wallet.dat file into Electrum.

Can that be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy wallet to Electrum or Multibit?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/2300/5406)