# how do I send my imported wallet on electrum

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, multibit, electrum

I have been able to transfer my bitcoin to electrum but am facing hard time to pay it or send my coins. A form appear and I fill out and there is only two option to choose to click create unsigned transaction and clear. I click on create unsigned transaction and there is no way I can send or pay my bitcoin to my counterpart. Please, I really need your help in this

Comment: Did you import an address to watch, or did you import private key?

Comment: Well, my motive was to import the private key to electrum but on the top of electrum software it is written (watching only) does it mean I have to find a way to import private keys ? . If I need to do that, please guide me. I am depressed

Comment: Yes. http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/36443/can-i-import-my-wallet-from-my-bitcoin-core-for-electrum