# how to move my Bitcoin core wallet to electrum while syncing

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, electrum, wallet-recovery, wallet.dat

How do I move my btc qt wallet to electrum while syncing?

Not address by address.

Removed some addresses already but I'm still missing some coins.

Don't understand the discrepancy.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send coins with Electrum from encrypted wallet created with Bitcoin Core](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/51480/send-coins-with-electrum-from-encrypted-wallet-created-with-bitcoin-core)

Comment: @chytrik no it doesn't.

Comment: I don't know of a way to import the wallet file; afaik the core wallet file is not compatible with electrum. You'll need to figure out which addresses still have coins on them, and then export priv keys from core, and import to electrum.

Comment: @chytrik I have removed all receiving addresses already but it does not equal the original balance. Don't really understand the discrepancy. That is why I wanted to move the whole wallet. Do you have any suggestions or ideas for the discrepancy in the balance?

Comment: If you ever sent coins out of the wallet, or moved them internally, then you likely have coins left in 'change addresses' as well. You could try the command `listunspent` or `listtransactions`, but if core is still syncing it may not be aware of coins sent to addresses at a point in time later than it is currently synced to.

Comment: @chytrik my btc qt looks like it will never fully sync. Keeps crashing after going through about 20% of the blockchain. Is there any other way?